# Multiple actions were found that match the request when I add another method to controller (RPC)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I'm developing an ASP.NET MVC 4 Web Api with C# and .NET Framework 4.0.

I'm having problems with this controller:

```
public class ASManagementController : ApiController
{
    private readonly IExceptionLogHelper m_ExceptionLoggerHelper;

    public ASManagementController(IExceptionLogHelper exceptionLoggerHelper)
    {
        m_ExceptionLoggerHelper = exceptionLoggerHelper;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage IsConnected()
    {
        [ ... ]
    }

    [HttpPut]
    public HttpResponseMessage DoConnect()
    {
        [ ... ]
    }

    [HttpPut]
    public HttpResponseMessage DoReset()
    {
        [ ... ]
    }
}
```

This is my `WebApiConfig` class:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{     
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        // More routes...

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "ASActionApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/asManagement/{action}",
            defaults: new { controller = "ASManagement" });
    }
}
```

When I do `https://localhost:44300/api/asManagement/DoConnect` I get the following error:

```
Multiple actions were found that match the request:
"ExceptionMessage":
   "System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage DoConnect() in type MyPtoject.Web.Api.Controllers.ASManagementController
    System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage DoReset() in type MyPtoject.Web.Api.Controllers.ASManagementController",
"ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException"
```

How can I fix this error?

If I remove `doConnect` method on `ASManagementController` it works. Do you know why?

A not very clean solution is to move `ASActionApi` defintion before `DefaultApi` on `WebApiConfig` class.

Comment: Are these all the methods in ASManagementController? or is there any that have the actionname attribute specifying DoConnect as the action name? and is there any routes defined before ASActionApi that could match the request URL?

Comment: Yes, these are all methods. No, there isn't any route that could match the requested URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting the ASActionApi before the DefaultApi.

> Incoming URLs are compared to route patters in the order the patters appear in the route dictionary (that is what we added the route maps to in our RouteConfig.cs file). The first route which successfully matches a controller, action, and action parameters to either the parameters in the URL or the defaults defined as part of the route map will call into the specified controller and action.

Comment: I have done what you have suggested and it works. But I don't understand why. If I don't change anything on `WebApiConfig` and I remove `doConnect` method on `ASManagementController` it works.

Comment: I believe the default routing rules for an ApiController only allow one Get and one Put.  If you have multiple Put's, then it doesn't know which one to choose.  Raven's solution is to override the default routing rules by moving ASActionApi in front of DefaultApi.